# Custom Lists: how to retrieve 3 most recent item submissions

Tags: list, caml-query, custom-list

I have currently 2 custom SharePoint lists. One represents questions, the other one answers.

Both lists have the default columns in place: ID, modified by date and username.

The requirement is now to get the 3 most recent items (indepent of the list) or submissions.

What is the easiest way to do this using CAML queries?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

If you need 3 most recent items independent of list then you can use Conten Query Web Part or Search Query Results Web Part. Constrain query by you's two list and

> Sort the items by Modified date, Then set item limit to 3... :)

Answer (score 0):

Kris i think you needto sort using modified date and you should be fine
See this :http://www.u2u.be/res/tools/camlquerybuilder.aspx
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Sort the items by Modified date, Then set item limit to 3... :)